# Toast android phone with welcome greeting message when a wireless network is available

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I am building an android app which once installed helps automating some of my home controls. As the first simple feature of the app, i want the phone to toast me with welcome message whenever i enter my home. 
I thought i could implement this by putting in a BroadCastReceiver with action name "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" and i assumed, whenever a new network is available, the broadcast receiver will be notified and i could check the SSID to see if i have arrived home.

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.WifiNetworksAvailableBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.WifiTester"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_wifi_tester" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My WifiNetworksAvailableBroadcastReceiver looks like:

```
public class WifiNetworksAvailableBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

protected static final String TAG = "MyApp";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
            WifiManager mMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Log.i(TAG, "------");
    for(final ScanResult result:mMgr.getScanResults()) {
        if(result.SSID.equals("<MY_HOME_WIFI_SSID>")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "======");
}
}
```

Now with the app installed. I enter my home but i do not get the toast. I tried running the app in the background but still i did not get the toast. Could anyone give an direction? Is my approach correct?

Comment: you recieve a broadcast only when there is change in network connection or you lose one.

Comment: Register to the broadcast when your activity starts and unregister when its detroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the receiver with the event [SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION).
Your receiver will be called every time a new wifi scan has been done, then you can check if your SSID is present in the list of available ones calling [getScanResults()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults%28%29) and eventually show the toast.

PS.
Have you registered your receiver?